# DataGridView Event "RowsAdded" doesn't show the correct RowIndex for the NewRow

Tags: c#, datagridview

During creating a new row in a `DataGridView` using the following command

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
```

I got a new row, but the e.RowIndex still shows the Index before the new created row.

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); 
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(Object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) 
{
       MessageBox.Show(e.RowCount + ";" + e.RowIndex); 
}
```

So in case I have 2 rows I would normaly have RowIndex 0 and 1.
But when adding programmatically a new line with ".add()" the event RowsAdded shows that the RowIndex is still 1 instead of 2, which is the new created Row.

Comment: Shouldn't dataGridView1.Rows.Add() take a parameter?

Comment: This is optional. If you would like to fill immediately data into the columns, it makes sense to have something like .add("1","2","3"), etc.
But even then it is not working.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, so I am guessing the issue is somewhere else in the datagridview settings.

Comment: I just did a brand new project without any tweaks or special settings and I could immediately reproduce. Could you send me the example app to check on my system? Which Framework did you use?

Comment: i cant seem to find the problem because its working with me. can you share the code of colums or data source

Comment: The code is pasted above. That's all I have written for the sample project.
In case you have added 2 rows not programmaticaly but just with typing into the grid. And then you stop at the last row and add with help of code .add(). What do you see as RowIndex? You should see RowIndex=2

Comment: here it starts from row index 1 then 2 and after add() it remains at 2 then 3 and so on

Comment: Then you have the issue as well. you said that it is working for you, but it seems not. Can you share you app?

Comment: https://www.pastiebin.com/582793f6d8a7f

Comment: see if the second paragraph in the Remarks section makes any sense https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded. My guess is that you are counting the last new blank row too

Comment: @Slai: But this proofs again that the code doesn't works as it's written there? Or do I missunderstood something here?
If you walk through the DataGrid and just type values in the last row, the Grid will "auto-add" the next new Row. Then the Event is triggered where then the right RowIndex will be shown. That is always working when using "just" the grid without any line of code. When you are now at the last row and you add via code as said, then you will find the same Index as before in the Event RowsAdded instead of current Row Incremented by 1.

Comment: the article cleared one issue but when i add row will edit the index was 1 as told in article that it would be one greater but after adding row with .add() it still shows 1 then it shows 2 .  means 1,1,2

Comment: Correct, but the common sense is for both the same. Either I use just the DataGrid for adding or if I use the code .add(). The rational behind is the same. I want to see in the RowsAdded event and there particular in the e.RowIndex the Index which has been added. That is why we have this Function for. Why should it show me an already existing rowIndex, which is not new but already there.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, or make it even more confusing. The row is inserted before the last new row:

```
dataGridView1.RowsAdded += (o, e) => Debug.Print(e.RowIndex + "\t" + dataGridView1.RowCount 
                                         + "\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "");  //  0   1   True
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();           //  0   2   False
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();           //  1   3   False
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();           //  2   4   False
```

but if the user adds row, then the new row is added after the last row that the user just entered:

```
1   2   True
2   3   True
3   4   True
```

Comment: I see Slai, but for me still not correct. The RowIndex is always 1 behind the RowCount. Therefore the "IsNew" will always throw False.
For me this is not a correct behaviour. Why we have a difference when manually typing versus Programatically. At the end it is the same what somebody tries to archive.

Comment: I think it is because the last row is not quite a "real" row, but more like a blank row template for the user to enter a new row. Also, this behaviour allows consistency whether [`.AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows) is set to True or False.

Comment: But at the end a new Row has been added. This new Row Triggers an Event so called private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(Object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) {
       MessageBox.Show(e.RowCount + ";" + e.RowIndex); 
}
When I use my .add(), the same happens basically. So I expect that in this case the same gets printed, as we have the same outcome; A new Row. From the Usecase it is absolute equal. But we have different behaviours.